# Split a large pandas dataframe grouped object alpha-numerically (0-9 A-Z) in group clusters of unequal size, but less than 500k rows in each cluster

Tags: python, pandas, file-io, xlsxwriter

I have a large dataframe with around 2 million rows with the following features:

```
'Month', 'Company name', 'Country', 'State', 'Area code', 'SR Category', 'SR Status'
```

I grouped the df based on the **Company name**.

```
grouped_comp = df.groupby(by='Company name')
```

I know I can use a for loop for exporting the grouped data

```
for name, group in grouped_comp:
    group.to_excel('file_name.xlsx', writer='xlsxwriter')
```

Now I need to split this df grouped object **alpha-numerically** (0-9 A-Z) in group clusters of unequal size, but less than 500k rows in each cluster, and export the files in **.xlsx**
(But, the files shouldn't split one company data into 2 files).
Say, file 1 contains company names contains company data beginning with *digits (0-9)*, file 2 contains company data beginning with the *letters A-F* .. so on so forth.

Comment: FYI for future readers, [Lakh / Lac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) = 100,000. So 500,000 rows per cluster.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from this dummy dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import string
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({'company': ['%scompany' % x for x in np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_uppercase+string.digits), size=100)],
                   'other': 'blah'})
```

```
>>> df.head()
    company other
0  2company  blah
1  Ocompany  blah
2  Hcompany  blah
3  Ucompany  blah
4  Scompany  blah
```

First we need to group the companies by their first letter (here digits/A-L/K-Z):

```
group = (df['company']
           .str.extract('^(?P<digit>\d)|(?P<AL>[A-L])|(?P<KZ>[K-Z])')
           .stack()
           .index.get_level_values(1)
        )
```

```
>>> group
['AL', 'AL', 'AL', 'AL', 'KZ', 'KZ', 'KZ', 'AL', 'KZ', 'KZ', 'KZ', 'AL',
 'KZ', 'KZ', 'KZ', 'KZ', 'KZ', 'AL', 'AL', 'KZ', 'KZ', 'AL', 'KZ', 'AL',
...
 'KZ', 'KZ', 'AL', 'AL', 'AL', 'KZ', 'AL', 'digit', 'digit', 'digit',
 'AL', 'KZ', 'digit', 'KZ', 'KZ']
```

Finally, we save per group as you did initially, including the group name in the filename:

```
for name, group in df.groupby(group):
    group.to_excel(f'group_{name}.xlsx', writer='xlsxwriter')
```